# Why does sort on Linux and on Cygwin return different results?

Tags: sort

Scenario:

```
# on Linux
$ cat r456.txt
e+e+l
e+e-c

$ cat r456.txt | sort
e+e-c
e+e+l

$ sort --version
sort (GNU coreutils) 8.30

# on Cygwin
$ cat r456.txt
e+e+l
e+e-c

$ cat r456.txt | sort
e+e+l
e+e-c

$ sort --version
sort (GNU coreutils) 9.0
Packaged by Cygwin (9.0-1)
```

Here we see that `sort` on Linux and on Cygwin returns different results. Why?

How to make `sort` on Linux and on Cygwin return the same results?

---

UPD. Locales:

```
# on Linux
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

# on Cygwin
$ locale
LANG=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="C.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="C.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="C.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

UPD2. I've changed all locales on Cygwin to `en_US.UTF-8`. However, `sort` still returns different results:

```
# on Linux
$ cat r456a.txt
u1
u-1

$ cat r456a.txt | sort
u-1
u1

# on Cygwin
$ cat r456a.txt
u1
u-1

$ cat r456a.txt | sort
u1
u-1

$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

How to fix?

Comment: @steeldriver How to check the locale?

Comment: Can reproduce it with C or C.UTF-8 versus en_US.UTF-8

Comment: @steeldriver See UPD.

Comment: @steeldriver See UPD2.

Comment: I can reproduce this using `sort` 8.32 on a Pi (Debian 12 "bookworm") vs 9.0 on Cygwin, both with locale `en_GB.UTF-8`

Comment: @pmor I removed my comments since you now seem to have ruled out locale differences